# Why JPA select query execution returns an exception with "canot execute query" message?

Tags: jpa, guid, jpql

The table in the database (Oracle 11g) is like this:

Name: LOG_ALIM_MAIL

Columns : ID_LOG RAW (automatically generated by SYS_GUID() in trigger), ALIMENTATION Number(9), DATE_LOG Date

PK: ID_LOG

FK: ALIMENTATION References ALIMENTATION.ID_ALIMENTATION (Number(9))

LOG_ALIM_MAIL class:

```
@Entity
public class LogAlimMail implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2243374060845658640L;

@Id
private Long idLog;

private Date dateLog;

private Alimentation alimentation;

public LogAlimMail() {

}

public Long getIdLog() {
    return idLog;
}

public void setIdLog(Long idLog) {
    this.idLog = idLog;
}

public Date getDateLog() {
    return dateLog;
}

public void setDateLog(Date dateLog) {
    this.dateLog = dateLog;
}

@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
public Alimentation getAlimentation() {
    return alimentation;
}

public void setAlimentation(Alimentation alimentation) {
    this.alimentation = alimentation;
}
}
```

Alimentation class:
    @Entity
    public class Alimentation implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5790314265385194058L;

private Long idAlimentation;

private Integer etat;

public Alimentation() {

}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "my_alimentation_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "my_alimentation_seq_gen", sequenceName = "SEQ_ID_ALIMENTATION")
public Long getIdAlimentation() {
    return idAlimentation;
}

public Integer getEtat() {
    return etat;
}

public void setEtat(Integer etat) {
    this.etat = etat;
}

public void setIdAlimentation(Long idAlimentation) {
    this.idAlimentation = idAlimentation;
}
}
```

I've got two questions:

1. I'm trying to execute the following select query:

   ```
   public List<LogAlimMail> getAllByIdAlim(Long idAlim) {
   String request = "select a from LogAlimMail a where a.alimentation.idAlimentation = " + idAlim;

   Query query = this.getEntityManager().createQuery(request);

   return query.getResultList();
   }
   ```

   I get the Exception :

   ```
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: idAlimentation of: administration.LogAlimMail [select a from administration.LogAlimMail a where a.alimentation.idAlimentation = 1]
   ```
2. I can't do the right JPA mapping between idLog (Long) and ID_LOG (RAW generated by SYS_GUID()).

Thanks

Comment: Post the complete stack trace, and the code of your entities.

Comment: Done. I posted more details.

Comment: You didn't post the code of Alimentation, and the exception tells you that the problem is related with Alimentation.idAlimentation.

Comment: Added. I already use Alimentation in queries like: "select alim from Alimentation alim where alim.etat = 1" without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Is idAlim a number? If not, you should use idAlimentation = '" + idAlim + "'";
Or better, use bound variables:

idAlimentation = :idAlim";
query.setString("idAlim", idAlim);

Comment: A Long should be a number(19), not number(9). At any case the exception logged looks from a different query than the query posted

Comment: We use number(9,0) for Long in other tables and we didn't have any error with that.